# maven-dependency-plugin unpack not being executed during phase

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm packaging an ejb and I need to include some .classes from a dependency into the jar, I'm trying to use the **maven-dependency-plugin** to unpack the artifact and put the files in my *${project.build.directory}/classes* directory during the *package* phase, but when I execute **mvn package** I dont see any log or reference to the maven-dependency-plugin (nothing happens), I even tried putting a invalid version of the plugin and It doesn't even throw exceptions.

Below my pom.xml

```
    ....
<packaging>ejb</packaging>
<name>myapp</name>

...repository and props

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>model</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                                    <includes>**/shared/*.class</includes>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>    
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

what am I missing?

PS: the artifact model is installed in the local repo and I have tried with other phases too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you remove the lines containing the text <pluginManagement> and </pluginManagement> the plugin should execute.  Just those two lines, not the lines in between.  pluginManagement is a marginally advanced feature.

PluginManagement provides configuration details to POMs that inherit from this POM.  However this section provides only the configuration details.  To actually be executed, the plugin must be explicitly referred to outside of a pluginManagement section.

See [POM Reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management)

Comment: This solved my issue! I wonder how `<pluginManagement>` got there...must have copied it from somewhere...

Comment: Are all plugins ignored in regards to execution or just certain ones when executing the parent pom when using pluginManagement?

Comment: wow, still valid in 2021. Thanks for sharing.